# Tools.jar could not be located by Android studio

Tags: java, android

Hello I'm wondering to start using Android studio but I am facing a settings problem.
I want to run on Android studio an Android app already working. But when I want to build the app there is an error message that indicates that Android studio don't find the tools.jar file of JAVA.
My Android studio version is 2020.3.1
I have initially install Java JDK 17 version and it seems that since JAVA 1.8 version the tools.jar file is not present anymore.
So I tried to downgrade Java to 1.8 version but the Android studio app is not compatible with versions older than JAVA 11.

So I was wondering if someone have faced the same problem and how I could overcome this.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: You need to make sure that 1) you installed a Java 8 JDK (not a JRE), and 2) your Android Studio is configured to >use< Java 8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I have installed a JDK and not a JRE version with a correct JAVA_HOME environment. 
Do you know which version of the SDK is compatible with Java 8 ? I don't find this information on the web.